# Using WCF with EF in many projects

Tags: c#, sql-server, wcf, entity-framework, service-reference

I have `WCF service` responsible for exposing services and connecting with local `database MSSQL`.

I generate client of this service in a few projects, e.g. `Proj1` and `Proj2`. In `Proj3` I have references to `Proj1` and `Proj2`. I want to use types from database, but they are in different namespaces (`Proj1.ServiceReference.TablePerson`, `Proj2.ServiceReference.TablePerson`).

How can I resolve this problem? I suppose using sth like converted/adapter for each type (table) is not the best solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do is create a separate project to create your service references in, and then have `Proj1` `Proj2` and `Proj3` all reference that project.  That way you will only have to generate one set of classes for your service reference.

Answer (score 3):

Have a shared dll with your classes and reference it form the server and from the client.

When you create a wcf reference, make sure that "reuse types from existing assemblies" is set. This will make generated proxies rely on the shared dll code and WILL NOT create new proxy types each time you create a web reference.